# NodeJS Zlib incorrect header check

Tags: node.js, zlib

OSX 10.12.6
node v12.2.0
gzip 1.10

I gzipped some plaintext and I'm trying to read it

```
fs = require('fs')
zlib = require('zlib')


fs.createReadStream(filepath, {'encoding': 'UTF-8'})
.pipe(zlib.createGunzip()) // createUnzip behaves similarly.
.pipe(somethingelse())
.on('finish', function(){
  console.log("finished reading");
});
```

This shows

```
Thrown:
Error: incorrect header check
      errno -3
```

Answer (score 1):

I hadn't realized that setting the UTF-8 encoding begins parsing in a different way. Removing the `{encoding: 'UTF-8'}` lets the zlib step decompress correctly, and my next step can consume directly from the stream.